# Converting RSS feed to Atom via Feedburner for existing blog

Tags: rss, blogs, atom-feed, syndication-feed

I have an RSS based blog that I now want to convert to Atom.  Feedburner can change the output format in one click.  Will my existing subscribers notice any change on the reader side? (other than taking advantage of the extra atom functionality)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I changed the output to Atom, posted a test blog post and checked my own feedreader.  No difference on the reader side so I'll assume this is standard behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Feedburner can adapt dynamically to whatever a user needs. This is taken from their site:

> SmartFeed: Reach the widest possible audience while publishing a single feed on your blog or site. Translates your feed on-the-fly into a format (RSS or Atom) compatible with your visitors' feed reader application.

Just enable that and you should be good to go :)

Comment: I just want to support Atom.  Basically to take advantage of it's timestamp field for updates (nothing similar in RSS).

If I switch from RSS to Atom for my next post will feedburned subscribers notice anything?

Comment: Go into Feedburner and enable SmartFeed. It will automatically switch between RSS or Atom depending on what your viewers use.

Comment: I want to force the user to Atom not give them a choice.

Comment: I'll assume it was user Josh who voted my accepted answer down - no one else seems interested so it must have been him.

Very petty.  I'd advise reading my question properly next time.

Comment: I voted down your answer because it is an incomplete solution. You tested in your own feed reader which probably supports both formats. You cannot expect your users' feed readers to have the same support. I was trying to help you out by giving you some options so you could still maintain support for your users. I guess I do not understand why you would want to 'force' your users to use one standard or the other.

Comment: Because Atom format has more features.  Either way you were trying to answer a question I did not ask.